# How to execute an SSH Command in a BASH Shell Script by way of a PHP program?

Tags: php, ssh

I am interested in having someone or as many technicians as possible to assist me,
or provide me with an understanding of how PHP processes an SSH command

`ssh username@hostname "ssh-script"`,

for remote access, embedded in a Bash Shell Script.

Initially I made many attempts to use PHP's `ssh2_command()`
function to no avail due mostly to the function not being recognized by the PHP interpreter.

My thinking is that perhaps SSH2 is not configured properly on my MAC OS X server.

I based my configuration on what I researched via the internet

- http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20010527220633471,
- http://www.3thirty.net/blog/?p=52

which appeared to install properly. Unfortunately, even with the good instruction, SSH2 does not work for me.

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: refer to http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24500986/execute-concurrent-ssh-commands#24500986

Answer (score 1):

You could try [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/)