# Execute concurrent SSH commands?

Tags: php, ssh

I want to write a little PHP script using the [`ssh2_*`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.ssh2.php) functions to deploy some code to several servers concurrently and run a few tasks.

Is this possible in PHP, or do I have to wait for each request to complete?

I can use a different language, but we're a PHP shop so I thought I'd stick with the familiar.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24500704/ssh2-exec-wait-end-of-a-process-to-run-next/24500766?noredirect=1#comment37930064_24500766 He **wants** it to wait for the first command to finish before running the second, but it doesn't. I think that should answer your question.

Comment: I think you need this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858883/run-php-task-asynchronously

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ssh2_exec()` allows multiple concurrent requests. See [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php#87745).

Comment: Aha! Maybe I'm creating problems where there isn't one then. I'll try this and see how it goes. Thanks!